# Answer exactly: $4 \cdot 1.1^x = 8.5$

Tags: logarithms

I'm having a little trouble formatting the title, but I think it's understandable. It's my first question here, and I'll do what I can to use the MathJaX notation correctly. Also, English is not my primary language, but I'll do my best to get myself understood.

I have the following equation:
$$4 \cdot 1.1^x = 8.5$$
They want the answer to be exact. Unfortunately I haven't been able to get further than this:
$$x = \frac{\log \frac{8.5}4}{\log 1.1}$$
I'm not even sure this is correct, but I think so. Anyone have a good idea how to get further? Maybe I need to start all over?

Comment: This is sufficient. You could evaluate numerically to get an approximate solution but it's not necessary.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Your use of MathJax looks good - I've made a few small edits to your post to make it just a bit more readable, and to make your notation consistent. As far as your problem goes, I'm not sure how much more you can simplify that. That looks to me as exact as you can get! You could simplify $\log(8.5/4) = \log(8.5) - \log(4)$, but I don't think that adds anything meaningful

Comment: Thank you both for your help. @AWertheim I checked your edit so from now on I should be able to provide better titles :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
4\times 1.1^x&=8.5\\
1.1^x&=\frac{8.5}{4}\\
x\log 1.1&=\log \left(\frac{8.5}{4}\right)\\
x&=\dfrac{\log \left(\frac{8.5}{4}\right)}{\log 1.1}\\
x&=\log_{1.1} {\left(\frac{8.5}{4}\right)}\\
\end{align}
What you have done seems to be correct. The last step isn't necessary.

Comment: Actually, steps (3) and (4) aren't necessary. You could get (5) from (2) immediately by the definition of log function.

Comment: @Kaster, I know. I was just trying to be a bit more methodical.

Comment: Thank you Inquest. I'll stick to the solution you've provided then, skipping the last step. I thought that I somehow could get rid of the log statements and end up with a regular fraction somehow.